# Did Batman ever develop a Super Soldier Serum?

Tags: dc, batman, marvel, captain-america, batman-beyond

Has Batman ever developed a [Super Soldier Serum](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Soldier_Serum) (similar to the one
that was successfully used on Steve Rogers/Captain America) and administered it on himself?

In the DC Universe (main DC continuity) Bruce Wayne/Batman is depicted as an individual with peerless intellect. In the movie *Batman Begins*, Batman is able to develop an **antidote** to the
fear-inducing hallucinogen developed by Crane and consequently administers it on Rachel and saves her.

However in *Batman Beyond*,  Bruce Wayne decides that given his old age his 
time as Batman is over and subsequently he retires. Thereafter, he trains Terry McGinnis to become the next Batman.

So, did Batman ever develop and test on himself a Super Soldier Serum that would have increased his stamina, speed and strength and also slowed down the aging process, allowing him to keep on fighting crime even in his old age?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is quite literally the plotline for the [Batman: Venom](http://kotaku.com/5904760/bruce-wayne-on-drugs-one-of-the-best-batman-stories-ever) story-arc in Legends of the Dark Knight volumes #16-20.

Batman realises that he's not strong enough to help people so starts taking an experimental steroid known as [Venom](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Venom). Suffice to say it starts out reasonably well, but goes bad after a very short amount of time. The (highly addictive) drug vastly increases his strength, but at the cost of making him mentally unstable and open to blackmail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did Batman develop Venom?

Comment: @Xantec - Nope. They were given to him by the shady-looking scientist type in the picture above. Wayne was aware of the research though. Theoretically, I guess he could have done it if he'd wanted to (unlike Captain America who's incapable of even pronouncing the stuff they gave him)

Comment: venom doesn't really seem like the same thing as the super solider serum though.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - No, but that's largely because the Super Soldier Serum is a Marvel creation and Batman lives in the DC universe. You could just as well ask why Batman's armour plating isn't made of vibranium.

Comment: It seems a potentially important point that Bane uses Venom to enhance his strength, at least in his early appearances

Comment: @RDFozz I'm pretty sure there was at least one storyline where Bane weaned himself off of Venom because he felt it was a crutch, only for it to come back up again either because he hit his own Godzilla Threshold or because the next writer forgot that was a plot point.